# Objective-C NSView Loading Issue

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

Hey everyone first questions i've asked here so please remember I'm new at this.

So I have been working on a custom button by using an `NSView` with a custom `NSView` class I made that draws a `NSDrawThreePartImage()` and detects the mouse events.

It works when it decides to load but loading is as everyone knows a MAJOR part of any application. What happens is when I click the build and run in Xcode and the window loads the `NSView` is sometimes there and works fine and other times its not there at all.

So why does the `NSView` draw only sometimes when application is launched?
Below is the button code, thanks in advanced :)

The .m file…

```
#import "BlackButtonLeft.h"

@implementation BlackButtonLeft

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        left = [NSImage imageNamed:@"black-left.tiff"];
        center = [NSImage imageNamed:@"black-center.tiff"];
        right = [NSImage imageNamed:@"black-right.tiff"];
        NSLog(@"image is valid? %@", [left isValid] ? @"yes" : @"no");
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    leftArrow = [NSImage imageNamed:@"chevron-left.tiff"];

    NSTrackingArea* trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds] options: (NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways) owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];

    NSDrawThreePartImage(_bounds, left, center, right, NO, NSCompositeSourceOver, 1, NO);
    [leftArrow drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10) fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1];
}

-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    left = [NSImage imageNamed:@"black-left-pressed.tiff"];
    center = [NSImage imageNamed:@"black-center-pressed.tiff"];
    right = [NSImage imageNamed:@"black-right-pressed.tiff"];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

-(void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    left = [NSImage imageNamed:@"black-left.tiff"];
    center = [NSImage imageNamed:@"black-center.tiff"];
    right = [NSImage imageNamed:@"black-right.tiff"];
    [myWebView goBack:0];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

@end
```

The .h file

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface BlackButtonLeft : NSView
{
    NSImage *left,*center,*right,*leftArrow;
    IBOutlet WebView *myWebView;
}
@end
```

Comment: Where are you using this class? Are you instantiating an instance in code? If so, show that. Are you instantiating it in a NIB? Explain what you did.

Comment: Well what I did was add a Custom View object(NSView) to the Main Menu.xib(Interface Builder). I then clicked on it add changed its class from NSView to BlackButtonLeft. I then click the run and build button, at the window launching it does one of two things. It decides to show it or show nothing. Every time you launch the app its random odds for some reason. I have others with similar code and they do the same thing to me. Funny thing is with them using similar code they all show at different run and builds. Every once in a while they will all show at the same time and function properly.

Comment: Also if I have one shot checked on the window and I hit minimize or close I get the following message...Aug  4 22:28:52 Mac-Pro.local Midnight[277] <Error>: Failed to create window context device
Aug  4 22:28:52 Mac-Pro.local Midnight[277] <Error>: CGWindowContextCreate: failed to create window context delegate.
2014-08-04 22:28:52.709 Midnight[277:303] _initWithWindowNumber: error creating graphics ctxt object for ctxt:0x10f0f, window:0xffffffff I can't even figure out what those mean, if I disable oneshot that fixes the min and close problem but might have to do with the NSView problem.

Comment: Is the NIB using auto layout? Have you set constraints on the custom view and resolve ambiguities? It may be that the view is always present but with ambiguous constraints that sometimes place it outside of its superview's bounds, so it's totally clipped.

Comment: Yes, I am using auto resizing in the .xib. However what constraints are you referring to? Width and Height is 27x27, using _bounds in NSDrawThreePartImage(_bounds, left, center, right, NO, NSCompositeSourceOver, 1, NO); as shown above...

Comment: Auto resizing is not the same thing as auto layout. In fact, they are mutually exclusive. If you're using auto layout, then you need to add constraints to the NIB that position the view properly. (Width and height refer to the view's size, not its position.)

Comment: I checked uses autoresizing and then used the chart with example next to it and clicked the outer top and outer left whisker things. Otherwise more help please.

Comment: What do you see in the logs if you add `NSLog(@"drawing %@ in %@ (%@)", left, NSStringFromRect([self bounds]), NSStringFromRect(_bounds));` to the bottom of `drawRect:`?

Comment: 2014-08-05 05:44:21.964 Midnight[331:303] drawing <NSImage 0x1019244c0 Name=black-left Size={7, 34} Reps=(
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x10192ab90 Size={7, 34} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=14x68 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x101928d20",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x10192d120 Size={7, 34} ColorSpace=sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace BPS=8 BPP=32 Pixels=7x34 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=2 CurrentBacking=<CGImageRef: 0x100533e40> CGImageSource=0x101928d20"
)> in {{0, 0}, {27, 27}} ({{0, 0}, {27, 27}})